# Set Cookie in React app works in localhost but not in production

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cookies, js-cookie, react-cookie

I am trying to set a cookie on the client side in my react web app.
I am using CRA deployed to Firebase.

Tried both `js-cookie` and `react-cookie` - in both cases I see that the set cookie code is running correctly.
When developing in localhost everything works perfectly - yet in production no cookie is ever being created.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your cookie named `__session`? Firebase infrastructure strips cookies named anything else at the networking layer meaning it never hits the backend. Try changing the cookie's name and test again.

Comment: How do you know the cookie isn't set? Is it by checking it in JavaScript or do you use a browser extension? Check properties `httpOnly` which makes the cookie invisible to JS and `secure` which will make the browser not accept the cookie if it's set on an unsecure (http) connection. Also check that the domain of the cookie corresponds to your url. Check headers in the network tab in the development tools to check whether subsequent requests contain the cookie or not.

Comment: @fast-reflexes Weirdly enough, now it looks like everything's working. Didn't change anything. I was checking it by inspecting the Application tab in Chrome DevTools and refreshing the items there. Maybe there have been some bug preventing me from seeing it, idk.

Comment: Did you try production mode in localhost? does that work?

Answer (score 0):

According to `react-cookie` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie)  `setCookie(name, value, [options])` and
`removeCookie(name, [options])` accepts `domain` key in options object. Are you using your production url as a value of `domain` key ?

Comment: I tried both with and without the domain :/

Comment: Just a thought - do check once if cookies are not blocked in the browser where you are testing. Also, check if there are any ad blockers blocking the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

For all my fellow developers who didn't find the answer to this weird issue yet:
The reason why it doesn't work (and it took me half a day to realise that) is that if you use [secure cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#secure), cookies will only work for an HTTPS domain. With HTTP, your app won't be able to read your cookies and will simply miserably crash. I hope it helps!